# Unable to get wanted output using for and range functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my homework assignment, I am using the for loop and the range function. I have to create a loop that prints

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 6
Hello 10
```

The question says that the number corresponds to the accumulated summation over the successive indexes, but I am not really sure how to implement it into my code. I was thinking it was setting the range from 0 to 10 and trying to make a formula, but nothing has come yet. Any help would be appreciated. It has to be in a for i in range function and loop for this assignment.

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
    print("Hello",i)
```

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Please write (add to question) your code at least

Comment: I have tried to use them for range and I function from 0 to 10 and trying to create a formula for it to calculate with the number of summations, but nothing has worked as of yet.

Comment: Posted the code that I am using, but this prints something else and doesn't take into account the summations, and I don't know why the post did this but the result should print on different lines not the same one

Comment: Maybe this will help you think `0+1=1`, `1+2=3`, `3+3=6`...

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking, I knew that the number of summations and then continuing the increase of 1 for the other number would have to be involved, but the only thing is me incorporating it is the bit that i'm trying to solve.

Comment: Two variables, one to keep count of indexes and another to print, now think, and a loop for sure, think on these terms @AdamHermon

Comment: Oh, I think I see, so would the variable to print just be the variable that counts the indexes plus one? And the bit of creating that variable to keep track is what I am stuck on, I will see what I can do.

Comment: You got it, since this seems a homework problem, it won't be helpful if we just provide you the code. Just think along those terms, plus your problem statement uses the exact language `number corresponds to the accumulated summation over the successive indexes`, which is `0+1=1, 1+2=3, 3+3=6` as I described above

Comment: Yeah, it won't be helpful as I am trying to learn. Would the variable for the number of indexes just be i, the print variable be i + 1, and the function would print that print variable?

Comment: Look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390988/for-statement-and-range-function-with-indexes

Answer (score 0):

may be this will be suitable :

```
i=0
step=1
while i<=10:
    print("Hello", i)
    i=i+step
    step=step+1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it must be using a for loop and the function range. I figured out that there must be two variables, one that keeps track for the amount of indexes, and another one that prints it, which is equal to the function that keeps track plus one. I am just having trouble creating that variable that holds on to the indexes

Comment: Think about how you could change the while loop into a for loop!

Answer (score 0):

the integers can be formed by cumulatively adding from 0 to 5 like so:

```
x = 0
for n in range(1,6):
    print(x)
    x += n
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
6
10
```

If you must add, a string `Hello` to each, depending on how far you are in your learning, there are 3 ways to go about this. Either:

1. `text = 'Hello %s' % x` - SUPER OLD string formatting for Python.
2. `text = 'Hello {}'.format(x)` - called %-formatting.
3. `text = f'Hello {x}'` - called F-strings ***suggested***.

So to complete the code:

```
x = 0
for n in range(1,6):
    print(f'Hello {x}')
    x += n
```

Output:

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 6
Hello 10
```