# For statement and range function with indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my assignment, I have to use a for loop and a range function for a program to print out the following, each on a separate line so it looks like a list.

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 6
Hello 10
```

I know that you have to create two variables, one that keeps track of the number of indexes and another that prints that, because the question states:
 (the number corresponds to the accumulated summation over the successive indexes). My problem is creating the function that does so keeping track of the indexes. Any guidance would be great. Thanks again in advance.

```
count_indexes = ?
print_statement = count_indexes + 1
for i in range(0,11,count_indexes):
    print("Hello",print_statement)
```

The expected result should print hello 5 times, each on different lines, each with different numbers on them, and the numbers should be 0,1,3,6,10.

Comment: It was meant to be a comma! So would I just say that in the loop using one of the variables?

Comment: Well, right now you're printing `count_indexes`.  So it needs to be 0 the first time through.  Then it needs to be 1.  Then 3, etc.  So you need to figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: Another question was asked for the same topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389718/unable-to-get-wanted-output-using-for-and-range-functions  Perhaps you can take a look

Answer (score 1):

> itertools module is a collection of tools for handling iterators
>
> [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)
>   - Make an iterator that returns accumulated sums, or accumulated results of other binary functions

```
from itertools import accumulate
for i in accumulate(range(5)):
    print(f'Hello {i}')
```

Or without any modules

```
cum_idx = 0
for i in range(5):
    cum_idx += i
    print(f'Hello {cum_idx}')
```

Comment: A bit too advanced for me! I am a beginner, what does itertools do?

Answer (score 0):

`Range` starts from 0 so you don't need to type it.

Here is sample solution:

```
counter = 0
for i in range(5):
    counter += i
    print('Hello', counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to increment step manually which can be done using a while loop. checkout difference between while and for loop.

The for statement iterates through a collection or iterable object or generator function.

The while statement simply loops until a condition is False.

if you use a while loop your code would look something like this:

```
count_indexes = 0
step = 1
while count_indexes < 11:
    print("Hello", count_indexes)
    count_indexes = count_indexes + step
    step = step + 1
```

output:

```
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 6
Hello 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are the triangle numbers. There is a closed form for calculating them so you don't need the keep track of an extra variable.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print('Hello', (i+1)*i//2)
Hello 0
Hello 1
Hello 3
Hello 6
Hello 10
```